# Print error on non-existent param in launch file

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A common mistake I make is setting a param with the wrong name, e.g.

```
<param name="min_x" value="1.0"/>
```

instead of

```
<param name="x_min" value="1.0"/>
```

Most of the time, the incorrectly named param does not exist.  I would like to know if there's a way to detect non-existent params and show a warning which will very likely hint in an incorrectly named param.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/352906/print-error-on-non-existent-param-in-launch-file/) by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1083 on 2020-05-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> A common mistake I make is setting a param with the wrong name, e.g.
>
> ```
> <param name="min_x" value="1.0"/>
> ```
>
> instead of
>
> ```
> <param name="x_min" value="1.0"/>
> ```
>
> Most of the time, the incorrectly named param does not exist.

Thing is: by adding that `param` element, `min_x` *does exist*. You've just created a parameter with that name.

> I would like to know if there's a way to detect non-existent params and show a warning which will very likely hint in an incorrectly named param.

That would be great, but how would `roslaunch` know which parameters your node(s) accept(s)? In ROS 1, there is no infrastructure for `roslaunch` to use. There is also no way for nodes to indicate which parameters they need/look at.

---

Edit: what would be good and which would also avoid many of the problems with this, is for nodes to *not* use any default values for parameters. Instead, they should fail immediately if they can't find a parameter.

In case you set `min_x`, but the node requires `x_min`, it prints an error and it's immediately clear you've made a mistake with the parameter name.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-21**:
In ROS 2, this is different: parameters have to be declared by a node (#q325960). This is exactly to make it explicit which parameters a node accepts ([ros2/demos/demo_nodes_cpp/src/parameters/set_and_get_parameters.cpp](https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/master/demo_nodes_cpp/src/parameters/set_and_get_parameters.cpp)). Whether this can be used by `launch_ros` I don't remember right now. But it is a step in the right direction.